# Test contract internal functions

Tags: ethers.js, mocha, hardhat, typescript

I'd like to test a contract internal functions. I used to [inherit the contract and test](https://medium.com/@danielque/solidity-unit-testing-internal-functions-4e9a728298a0) it with truffle but that involved Solidity test files.

Can I do the same with my current stack (hardhat/mocha/ethersjs/typescript) or are there better alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All Solidity development frameworks are subject to the same limitations of Solidity language, so unfortunately there is nothing better.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a plugin for this now: `hardhat-exposed`; though I didn't try it yet.